# C++ thread safety without atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading

I understand that atomics provides guarantees for multithreaded programs, but in the following case, is there any problem if I don't use atomics?

```cpp
struct Foo  {
  Foo() : a(0) {
    findA(&a);
  }

  int a;
}

void findA(int *a) {
  // spaws a thread...
  // the following runs on a separate thread
  *a = 5; // find the actual value of a (5 for example)
}
```

Once the constructor is done, no other thread will ever write to `a`, so can I safely read/write to it without locking?

Comment: You can safely read and write to it just as safely as a non-multithreaded program can read or write any object or variable.

Comment: When you say that "no other thread will ever write to `a`" does that include the thread that runs the `Foo` constructor and the call to `findA`? If it accesses `a` while the new thread is running you still have a data-race.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Only the main thread that runs the constructor will read/write to it (it's in this thread that we use `Foo` objects)

Comment: Make a [mre] and it'll probably be easier to say whether it's safe or not.

Comment: Does the thread spawned by `findA` join before the `}`?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ memory model states that if one thread writes to a variable and another reads without those operations being sequenced, no guarantees are placed on the operation of the program at all.

There are a bunch of ways to sequence access; atomics is just one of them.  But this kind of UB is really easy to trigger in naive multithreaded code.

A goal of that rule is to permit single threads local state to be reasoned about.  For example, if a thread reads `7` from `a`, and it knows it did no synchronization, nor any operation that could edit `a`, it does not have to reload it from memory, clear cpu caches, or any of that overhead.  It will know the value remains `7`.

Comment: Ok so atomics are a way to have guarantees, but I don't want to use atomics because it's for members of a struct and I don't want the external code to know about that. So can I just use regular member variables and manually insert memory fences where needed to have the guarantees? Because also, my variables are mostly ints and since reads/writes to ints are already atomic, so I could just set the variables directly and insert fences to have guaranteed?

Comment: @jojo Thread safety is a relational property.  One operation is thread safe relative to another.  If one thread is reading "plain" memory it does not know another thread could modify, I am unaware of a way to modify that data that does not result in UB in the C++ memory model.  So I have no clue.  You probably do not know the details you need to share to ask the question whose answer will solve your problem.  The answer could be "you can't do that" quite easily.

Comment: Engafe in the question comments and follow their advice.  A mcve is key.