# C++ thread safe variables without std::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

If I have a struct with some members in it, and I want to have differents threads that read into these structs. In this case, I don't need to do anything because I only read, but if I ever want to *write* to a member, do I have to use atomics and force everyone to explicitly load the atomic everywhere? Just because of one single write that I occasionally do?

Comment: If those writes and reads may happen at the same time, then, you need atomics. Note that since C++20, you can use `std::atomic_ref`, which enables the variables to have non-atomic types.

Comment: BTW, don't ask basically the same question twice. This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67686525/580083. Instead, edit the original question as suggested in its comments.

Comment: First sentence: "differents threads that read into these structs" -- "read from" or "write into"? Or maybe both? Please clarify that and also remove "C++" from the title, which is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variables as private and access them through getters and setters, and guard their access with a std::scoped_lock:

in cpp:

```
std::mutex aMutex;

int getInteger() const
{
  std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> aLock(aMutex);
  return m_integer;
}

void setInteger(int iInteger)
{
  std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> aLock(aMutex);
  m_integer = iInteger;
}
```

Comment: How is this on topic?

Comment: If there is only a single writer there is no need for a mutex. Instead atomic variables can be used. The OP is specifically asking for this scenario.

Comment: @ciamej There is indeed a single writer but there is also a reader (or several readers). If they can read at the same time the writer modifies the variable, a mutex **is** needed (or use an atomic variable).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean - a mutex *is not* needed when using an atomic variable, and there is no good reason to use it since atomic store/load is much better performance wise and simply more natural.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi reader and writer you should use synchronization methods.

in your case because your read and write not in proper order you should synchronize them. imagine you read and write value in same time if you dont have enough luck your reader thread will read fast and store value in register(or other location) and immediately you write new value and therefore your value updated and previous value is gone.

most famous synchronization method is mutex.
example:

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mutex;

mutex.lock();
//enter critical section
mutex.unlock(); //exit critical section
```

another good synchronization method is **reader and writer lock**.
in this method if you going to read value you can lock multi times and read value from multi thread but if you going to write when you call lock on writer side other thread cannot read or write value because it is currently under writing.

another good synchronization method is **spin lock** in this method you just run busy loop until you can gain access for manipulate variable. the good point of this method is that because we run busy loop therefore it's faster than mutex because in mutex you switching to kernel mode which is slow(but beware you should hold spinlock for just little amount of time)

they are many other synchronization method but i recommend you to use mutex or atomic variables.

Comment: How is this on topic?